# What does "in one's hand" mean in this case?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> Above these apparent hieroglyphics was a figure of evident pictorial
>   intent, though its impressionistic execution forbade a very clear idea
>   of its nature. It seemed to be a sort of monster, or symbol
>   representing a monster, of a form which only a diseased fancy could
>   conceive. If I say that my somewhat extravagant imagination yielded
>   simultaneous pictures of an octopus, a dragon, and a human caricature,
>   I shall not be unfaithful to the spirit of the thing. A pulpy,
>   tentacled head surmounted a grotesque and scaly body with rudimentary
>   wings; but it was the general outline of the whole which made it most
>   shockingly frightful. Behind the figure was a vague suggestions of a
>   Cyclopean architectural background.
>
> **The writing accompanying this oddity was, aside from a stack of press
>   cuttings, in Professor Angell’s most recent hand**; and made no pretense
>   to literary style. What seemed to be the main document was headed
>   “CTHULHU CULT” in characters painstakingly printed to avoid the
>   erroneous reading of a word so unheard-of.

[H. P. Lovecraft, Collected Stories](http://www.turtlereader.com/authors/h-p-lovecraft/collected-stories-part-1-day-21-of-277/)

What does ***in his most recent hand*** mean here?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. [Please provide some context](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a secondary meaning of the word hand - [style of handwriting or penmanship](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hand) (definition 5).  It's becoming obsolete now, as more and more writing is done with keyboards.

"His most recent hand" would mean his most recent style of writing, implying that it had changed gradually over the course of his life.

Comment: It could equally mean that his handwriting had changed suddenly.